# How to properly hide address bar from Firefox 96.0?

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I want to hide the address bar leaving only the opened tabs bar visible, I've tried with 2 methods editing the userChrome.css, one works (but it generates a lot of top-spacing), while the second method removes the top-spacing, but it also stops the web pages from being loaded.

Here what I tried with screenshots:

- With the first method I've added this to the userChrome.css

  #nav-bar {
  visibility: hidden !important;
  }

And that is the one which generates the extra top-spacing:

[First method screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKCl4.png)

- With the second method I've added this instead

  #nav-bar {
  display: none !important;
  }

This one lets me obtain exactly what I want but, as I said, it also stops web pages from being loaded (see screenshot):

[Second method screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9yqr.png)

How can I reach the same result of the second screenshot, but with web pages being actually loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the correct parameter was:

```
#nav-bar { visibility: collapse !important; }
```